# Theano on Azure DSVM

Tags: azure, deep-learning, theano, azure-dsvm

I am trying to use Theano on the Azure DSVM which is a preconfigured VM for Data Science. Is anyone aware of such a VM and does it support Theano out of the box?

> WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be unable to execute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will default to Python implementations. Performance will be severely degraded. To remove this warning, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.

Anyone with some experience in this regard?

Comment: Are you using the Azure DSVM on N-Series VM with GPU?

Comment: Yes I am using the N-Series VM with Tesla GPU.

Answer (score 3):

We recently released a new version of the Data Science Virtual Machine for Linux (Ubuntu) edition which has Theano (and several other popular deep learning tools) pre-installed that you can use on either NC-Series GPU Azure VM or any CPU only VM.

More info:

http://aka.ms/dsvm/ubuntu

http://aka.ms/dsvm/ubuntu/docs

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue since Theano has dependency on g++. So what i did is the following:

1) Install anaconda from [here](https://www.continuum.io/downloads).
3) Open anaconda command prompt and write the following command. This will install Theano with all its dependencies including g++ and others.

```
conda install theano
```